# 10Base-2 connection to new pc

Tags: router, internet-connection, network-adapter, rj-45

So I have a very old pc running windows xp, and I am currently using a pci network card with a 10Base-2 Internet interface, which I am using for Internet connection on the pc. The 10Base-2 cable goes from my house to the shed which includes the office the pc is in. As for the connection from the router to the office pc: there's a MC15 ethernet media converter which converts ethernet from my router to 10base2 which has the bnc connectors. the coax cable running under my front yard is about 25 meters long.

Now I want to upgrade to a new pc, but newer motherboards are no longer made with pci, so I would no longer be able to use the network card, and I honestly doubt it would work due to drivers and such. I have looked for bnc to rj45 adapters, but those cost like a 100 euros which I'm not prepared to pay for this.

Is there any cheaper alternative I can use?

Wifi is not really an option since there's a lot of walls between my router and the office the pc is in (current router makes it there with 0-1 stripes), and replacing the bnc cable with a cat 6 would mean ripping open the whole front yard.

EDIT:
[This is the network card.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDbe8.jpg)

Couldn't get a clearer picture, sorry.

Comment: There are motherboards with PCI slots. Whether your BNC PCI card has driver for newer OS - I don't know. Why not upgrade both PC and move completely to RJ45? (of course it does mean you have to rip out the existing BNC to CAT6.. but it may be a better way forward than trying to re-use existing infrastructure). Another option if your shed and home shares the same power line, you can try using the PowerLine AV that re-use the power for LAN connection.

Comment: Power grids are separate. As for mobo, say I get one with pci and it doesn't work, I'm kinda screwed.

Comment: BNC is just the connector.  You haven't described at all what you really have in place.  Is it 50 Ohm coax cable?  Is this Ethernet over coax?  What are the specifics of this PCI adapter?  What is at the other end of the cable?

Comment: ripping open the front yard?  how about a rugged cable, a cable with a rugged jacket, just going along your yard. (though i guess that'd cost a bit). And if you have a router and an office then presumably both are near a plug, so have you heard of / tried ethernet over mains(though that'd also cost a bit). i'm rather unfamiliar with converting bnc.. i think i first got broadband internet about 15 years ago and it was already cat5. And prior to that I had dial up and no LAN.

Comment: @barlop7 like I said in a previous comment, the power grids of my house and shed are separate so a power line won't work

Comment: @sawdust There is a media converter in my home, the "MC15 Ethernet Media Converter" which converts ethernet to 10base2. So it's ethernet over coax I think.

Comment: If you already spend that cash on one side of line why not spend it on the other side as well? An additional WiFi Antenna which would be directed could help as well.

Comment: why not search the used ads for a 10BaseT hub with bnc?  That used to be a common configuration

Comment: There's a Netgear EN116 on eBay right now located in Italy, I don't know whether links are allowed in comments so you'll have to search for it.

Comment: @seth the one side has been there for over 10 years.

Comment: @marctxk if I were to buy that thing I'd have 15 unused ethernet ports on it..

Comment: Consider Wi-Fi.  Yes, I read your reason against it.  Walls?  Fine.  But consider using Wi-Fi to go from building to building, and then having additional networking equipment/cabling that goes through/around the walls.  Granted, might be pricier than 100 Euros, but might also be a much better (faster, perhaps also more reliable) solution than very-old cabling.

Comment: I suppose this question serves as a good lesson.  In my opinion, the right approach isn't to bury a cable.  The right approach is to bury a pipe.  That way, you can replace cabling (or add more cabling, like adding a phone cord to the coax cable) without re-digging.  (Then again, I haven't personally done such a project, so I may be ignorant about important mitigating factors, quite possibly including cost.)

Comment: @TOOGAM It's not only walls, but also quite some range to encompass. I currently have a modem/router and a separate router. The modem/router has a really crappy range, even in my room above it the latency is impossible to work with. The separate router actually reaches the office, but it's the same story as the modem in my room. It gives 1 stripe at max there, and is very unstable there. As for the pipe, the whole idea of this question is to have to rip open the yard as a very last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10Base-2 is not the same as "Ethernet over coax" even though the cable used for it is technically a coaxial cable. Ethernet over coax is about re-purposing existing CATV or cable TV cable. 10Base-2 cable has a different impedance. For this answer I assume you actually do have 10Base-2 running under your front yard.

To do it right, you need another media converter, also called a transceiver, to connect the Ethernet jack on a new PC to the 10Base-2 network you have under your yard. You'd hook it up just like the one you have going to the router at the other end. (But see below about grounding.) I'm surprised these are still being made. A used one would be fine, as there are no moving parts or software drivers.

As @marctxk said in a comment, 10Base-T Ethernet hubs often had that feature built-in, with a BNC connector for 10Base-2 on the back. This was partly to facilitate the transition to twisted pair, and partly because 10Base-2 was still a convenient way to interconnect them. Sure, you'd have some unused ports, but I don't see how that matters if you can find one cheap.

I have to point out, however, that 10Base-2 has a top speed of 10Mbps, which is literally 100 times slower than typical (consumer-grade) Ethernet today. You might want to think about alternatives, like maybe WiFi with external directional antennae.

As for finding a PC that still has PCI slots and re-using your existing network interface card, I agree with your concern about device drivers. If your card were a common make and model, like the ubiquitous 3Com 3c5x9, device drivers would probably be available. But from your blurry photo that does not appear to be the case.

Also, you mentioned that your house and shed have separate electrical service. This means you have to be especially careful about whether and where you ground that cable. Most of all, you do **not** want it grounded at both ends, because that will create a ground loop.

[image: Rg58 cable with BNC T connector, terminator, and chain]

10Base-2 is meant to be grounded - at one end only - via the chain shown in the photo. It goes to a grounding screw near the BNC connector, which is connected to chassis ground. If yours isn't grounded at all you're probably fine. But if you grounded it at the router end, then you **should not** also ground it at the PC end.

Comment: It is 10Base-2, since the media converter doesn't convert to anything else. As for Speed, it hardly matters for only browsing some forums and watching a video here and there, nothing that isn't being done on the current windows XP machine. I do have a router with external directional antennae, but that one reaches the office with 0-1 stripes (at least on my phone, a samsung galaxy s4) and barely works better than the 10Base-2 connection it currently has, since it is everything but stable.

Comment: When you say ground the cable, what exactly do you mean? The Media converter in place has and needs a power supply, and if I were to get one of those hubs it would need a power supply as well.

Comment: @Arrrow Added photo to show grounding chain

Comment: Ah right. Like I said in another comment I didn't even know 10Base-2 existed since it was my dad who put it all in place. Forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

> Bnc connection to new pc

BNC is just the connector; it does not specify the type of signal or protocol in use.
BNC is the better but expensive alternative to F-connectors for terminating coaxial cable.

> I have looked for bnc to rj45 adapters, ...

You're using the wrong search criteria.
You should search for "Ethernet over coax".
Typical extenders will use the cheaper F-Connector rather than BNC, so you will simply need to also use BNC-female-to-F-male adapters. [image: BNC female to F male adapter]

You need to determine the impedance of the coax in place; i.e. do you have 50 Ohm or 75 Ohm coax?  Check the cable itself for markings.
Be sure to confirm that the Ethernet extender that you chose is compatible with the impedance of your coax.

Comment: Yeah call it ignorance. Totally my bad. I thought I could just get something that converted to RJ-45, seems it's not that easy. Seems It's 10Base-2, I Didn't even know it existed earlier since I'm actually asking for my dad, and he's the one who put all of it together around 15 years ago. Like the answer below suggests, I should probably get another media converter or a 10Base-2 ethernet hub.